# Is there macro to create HashSet in Rust

Tags: rust

In Rust, we can create a Vector with macro `vec![]`.

```
let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

Is there any similar macro that allow us to create a `HashSet`?

From the doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html, I notice that we have `HashSet::from`:

```
let viking_names = HashSet::from(["Einar", "Olaf", "Harald"]);
```

However, that requires us to create an array first, which seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: https://lib.rs/crates/map-macro

Comment: There is no cost for creating a array, since in rust objects are created on the stack by default, so there will be no allocation. Especially if the array is static. Vectors are different though, they need dynamic space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library doesn't have a macro for this. [This crate](https://lib.rs/crates/map-macro) does provide one though.

As for the wastefulness, creating an array of string literals is pretty cheap, and is almost certainly optimized away.

Comment: Creating an array of a few thousand `&'static str` was not optimized away when I tried (with rustc 1.61). I think the optimizer just gave up.

Answer (score 2):

If you fear the overhead of constructing the `HashSet` at runtime, or want this to be a `static`, the [phf](https://docs.rs/phf/latest/phf/macro.phf_set.html) crates might help you.